# Parallel structure with a negative

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parallelism

Would this sentence follow the rules of parallel structure?

> In order to improve your country, you should take care of the environment, avoid throwing litter, help society, and don't use plastic.

I could make this sentence better by changing the last part to "avoid using plastic", but I was wondering if the above sentence is correct in its original form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the parallel structure at work:

> ✘ In order to improve your country, you should take care of the environment, <sup><s>you should</s></sup> avoid throwing litter, <sup><s>you should</s></sup> help society, and <sup><s>you should</s></sup> don't use plastic.

Assuming you want to maintain a parallel structure, the sentence is incorrect because of this:

> ✘ You should don't use plastic.

---

However you rephrase the final list item, it should be in a manner that makes it grammatical with a *you should ___ plastic* structure.

Your own suggestion would be fine. As would some others:

> ✔ You should ***avoid using*** *plastic*.
>   ✔ You should ***stop using*** *plastic*.
>   ✔ You should ***not use*** *plastic*.